# Как найти следующее четное число?

Tags: c++

на вход дается положительное целое число, нужно найти последующее четное число, причем программа должна быть БЕЗ использования условного оператора.

К примеру:

> Ввод: 8
>   Вывод: 10

Comment: Согласен, легкая. А вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: каким должен быть код? у меня есть вот это, но оно не выполняется для нечетных чисел:#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a, b;
    cin>> a;
    b=(a/2+1)*2;
    cout<< b;
  return 0;
}

Comment: добавьте 2 и в полученное число в самый правый бит выставьте 0

Comment: Ну так вы бы код привели в самом вопросе...

Comment: `b = (a+2)/2*2`

Comment: Или вот: `i+2-i%2`

Comment: @Dilya.skywalker у меня ваш код работает, приведете число на котором этот код выдает не верный результат

Comment: @Rikitikitavi например, ноль

Comment: ааа, в с++ же он округляет до целых, просто чисто математически не было правильно

Comment: @Senior Pomidor на нуле тоже работает `(0/2 + 1) * 2 == 2`

Comment: @Rikitikitavi как сказал юзер, "но оно не выполняется для нечетных чисел". а 2 - это четное число

Comment: Может я чего-то не понял, но должно быть такое соответствие:`0->2; 1->2; 2->4; 3->4` и т.д. и для всех чисел алгоритм `b=(a/2+1)*2` выдает этот результат

Answer (score 3):

Для положительных чисел подойдет это:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int in;
    while(true) {
        std::cout << "In: ";
        std::cin >> in;
        std::cout << "Out: " << (in - in % 2 + 2) << std::endl << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Если нужна поддержка отрицательных чисел, то `(in - in % 2 + 2)` заменить на `(in - std::copysign(1, in) * (in % 2) + 2)`

Оба варианта защищены от деления на 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int inputNum,nextEvenNum;
    cin >> inputNum;
    nextEvenNum=(inputNum/2+1)*2;
    cout << nextEvenNum;
    return 0;
}
```

Как вариант - при делении на два отсекаем остаток, так как делим в int'ах, прибавляем единицу и умножем обратно на два.

Comment: Также возможен вариант с использованием побитовых сдвигов вместо операций деления/умножения: 
`nextEvenNum=((inputNum>>1)+1)<<1;`